# GitHub GUI move folder from one repo to another

Tags: github, github-api

I have multiple repositories under my account, and I placed a folder into the incorrect repo.

Is there a way use the GitHub web interface to move that folder from one repo to another?

Answer (score 2):

From GitHub GUI alone, I don't think so.

You can delete files from the web GUI, but you still need to push your folder content from a local cloned repo (the right one this time)

Note: even if GitHub GUI referred to [GitHub Desktop](https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/#desktop), you would still need to push.